# Pegar informações de span dentro de div

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tenho a seguinte estrutura em HTML:

```
<div class="ui fluid search dropdown procuraAluno selection multiple active visible">

   <select name="ci_direcionado" id="cisOptions" multiple="">
      <option value=""></option>
   </select>

   <i class="dropdown icon"></i>

   <input class="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" >

   <span class="sizer" style="">Anderson Amorim</span>

   <span class="sizer"></span>

   <div class="text filtered"></div>

   <div class="menu transition visible" tabindex="-1" style="display: 
   block !important;">

   <div class="message">No results found.</div>

</div>
```

Como faço para pegar o text do primeiro span? Já tentei de várias formas, como por exemplo:

```
 $(".procuraAluno").closest('.sizer').first().change(function(){
    console.log($(".procuraAluno").next().text());
 });
```

Porém, sem sucesso.

Lembrando que a criação do 2 span é inerente minha vontade, o próprio template que o cria.

Grato.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` procura pelo por elementos em niveis hierárquicos superiores ao do elemento em questão - no caso `.procuraAluno`.

Como o `span` está em nível hierárquico inferior ("dentro" de `.procuraAluno`), você pode usar `find`.

```
var text = $(".procuraAluno").find('.sizer').first().html();
```

---

#### Disparar evento `change`

```
var $span = $(".procuraAluno").find('.sizer').first();

$span.on("change", function() {  // "Vigia" mudanças no `span`
  alert($(this).html());
})

$span.html("Olá");        // Altera o valor do span
$span.trigger("change");  // Dispara o evento `change`.
```

Comment: Legal!! Deu certo, porém ainda tenho uma dúvida, estou tentando usar essa mesma estrutura para detectar um evento change e esta dando errado :/
Da seguinte forma:

$('.procuraAluno').find('.sizer').first().change(function(){
});

Comment: Alterei a resposta para "vigiar" o evento `change`. Se você quer que a função seja invocada ao alterar o `span` dinamicamente, você pode disparar o evento com a função `trigger`.

Comment: Eu gostaria de disparar quando houvesse mudança no text mesmo, daí fiz como vc mostrou. Porém o evento change não é disparado...

Comment: Você está substituindo `html` por `text`? Se for isso, nesse [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WesleyGoncalves/g8f2hpq1/) que eu fiz deu certo.